# How is a work title marked up when it's not being cited?

Tags: html, markup

To cite a work in HTML, you use `<cite>`:

```
In <cite>The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King</cite>, the author includes several appendices.
```

What if I want to mention a work without actually citing it? Is `<cite>` still the correct element or should I use something else?

```
I read <cite>The Lord of the Rings</cite> when I was thirteen.
```

I didn't see any guidance [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite), and the closest question I could find here was [(X)HTML Markup for Book Titles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/982157), which is about what to use instead of `<em>` for a book title but doesn't distinguish between a citation and a mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The WHATWG spec indicates](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element) that `<cite>` should be used for both citations and mentions:

> The `cite` element [represents](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#represents) the title of a work (e.g. a book, a paper, an essay, a poem, a score, a song, a script, a film, a TV show, a game, a sculpture, a painting, a theatre production, a play, an opera, a musical, an exhibition, a legal case report, a computer program, etc.). This can be a work that is being quoted or referenced in detail (i.e., a citation), or it can just be a work that is mentioned in passing.